# why in this code the sort in C++ is much slower than qsort in C (for string array)?

Tags: c++, c, performance, sorting, c++11

In the book **The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)**, *Stroustrup* say that ***sort*** is much faster than ***qsort*** , but in my experiment, I got a different result, could any one help me to explain Why?

Here is my code :

```
double begin_time=0, end_time=0, elapsed_time=0;

vector<string> vs1 = { "fsfaa", "errer", "weesa", "yuyre", "wedsa", "xcxcx" };
begin_time = clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    std::sort(vs1.begin(), vs1.end());
}

end_time = clock();
elapsed_time = double(end_time - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("\n\nElapsed time: %f\n", elapsed_time);

const char* vs[] = { "fsfaa", "errer", "weesa", "yuyre", "wedsa", "xcxcx" };
begin_time = clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    std::qsort(vs, sizeof(vs) / sizeof(*vs), sizeof(*vs), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))compare_function);
}

end_time = clock();
elapsed_time = double(end_time - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("\n\nElapsed time: %f\n", elapsed_time);
```

and,

```
int compare_function(const void * a, const void * b) {
const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

return strcmp(pa, pb);
```

}

Here is the result(Windows/Visual Studio):

```
Elapsed time: 0.245000
Elapsed time: 0.090000
```

**Update:**
Thanks for advice, I had changed the code as follow:

```
int compFunc_2(const void * a, const void * b) {
    const char *pa = *(char**)a;
    const char *pb = *(char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa, pb);
}

bool compFunc(const char *c1, const char *c2)
{
    return strcmp(c1, c2) < 0;
}

string gen_random_str(int len)
{
    string str;
    string w = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        str += w[rand() % sizeof(w)];
    }
    return str;
}

char *convert(const std::string & s)
{
    char *pc = new char[s.size() + 1];
    strcpy(pc, s.c_str());
    return pc;
}


int main()
{

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    const int str_num = 1000000;
    vector<string> vs;
    vector<char*>  vc;
    vector<char*>  vc2; //
    char**  as = new char*[str_num];

    for (int i = 0; i < str_num; i++)
    {
        string tmp = gen_random_str(10);  // length is 10
        vs.push_back(tmp);
        as[i] = new char(tmp.size() + 1);
        strcpy(as[i], tmp.c_str());
    }
    transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::back_inserter(vc), convert);
    transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::back_inserter(vc2), convert);



    double begin_time = 0, end_time, elapsed_time;

    begin_time = clock();
    std::qsort(&vc[0], str_num, sizeof(vc[0]), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))compFunc_2);
    end_time = clock();
    elapsed_time = double(end_time - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n[1] vector<char*>(qsort) Elapsed time: %f", elapsed_time);

    begin_time = clock();
    std::sort(vc2.begin(), vc2.end(), compFunc);
    end_time = clock();
    elapsed_time = double(end_time - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n[2] vector<char*>(sort) Elapsed time: %f", elapsed_time);



    printf("\nOther test:");
    begin_time = clock();
    std::qsort(as, str_num, sizeof(as[0]), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))compFunc_2);
    end_time = clock();
    elapsed_time = double(end_time - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n[3] char array(qsort)   Elapsed time: %f", elapsed_time); 

    begin_time = clock();
    std::sort(vs.begin(), vs.end());
    end_time = clock();
    elapsed_time = double(end_time - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n[4] vector<string>(sort) Elapsed time: %f", elapsed_time);

    // clean
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And, I got the result on my computer:

```
[1] vector<char*>(qsort) Elapsed time: 1.752000
[2] vector<char*>(sort) Elapsed time: 6.004000
Other test:
[3] char array(qsort)   Elapsed time: 1.691000
[4] vector<string>(sort) Elapsed time: 46.663000
```

as some say, yes, there is **no comparison** between [1] and [3]/[4](because of the different data), but I'm still confused about [1] and [2], why the **sort** seems still slower? (I had closed the Optimize in VS), any help would be great appreciate .

Comment: Your timing is flawed, you only sort the vector in the *first* iteration of the loops, then you sort an already sorted container, which is usually not a good case for many sorting algorithms.

Comment: Do you think sorting an array of size 6 is a good benchmark?

Comment: Your test is ill-designed because after the first iteration, you keep sorting an already sorted array. (And as Ajay already said, size 6 is, sorry, grotesque.)

Comment: You should also take a look at your optimization levels, and check the generated code to make sure the compiler perhaps doesn't do some optimization for the `qsort` case that it misses in the `std::sort` case.

Comment: Since nobody has answered yet, I suggest you withdraw this question, fix the issues that have been pointed out, and resubmit if there is still a material time difference.

Comment: Moreover, you `std::sort` a `std::vector` of `std::string`s and compare it to `qsort`ing an array of `char*`s

Comment: An implementation of sort will probably revert to something like insertion-sort for an array of size 6. Try 6000 or 60,000. Also, shuffle the array before every call to sort.  Your test would not pass a code-review.

Comment: Enable the optimzer, aka build in Release mode,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code posted does not demonstrate the problem as described.

Comment: This is **not** how you bench code :-/ I'd recommend reading a nice tutorial about microbenching code, and if you don't want to set this up locally, you can use http://quick-bench.com. But only after you've read more about microbenching in general.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ... Thank you all very much for your quick reply, I am totally a novice in C++, so Sorry for my ugly code. I will fix it. Thx

Comment: To downvoters: sure, this benchmark is terrible. But the question as a whole is fine - it shows effort, has MVCE, and is pretty clear.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2017 I get the times 0.045 and 0.043 seconds, respectively.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question because it seems fine to me. Implicit in the question as asked is a false assumption about why the questioner is getting the result he gets, but I don't think that is a good reason to reject the question.

Comment: @el.pescado As policy, I downvote any C++ performance question that does not include the command line used to compile, or at least strong evidence that it isn't an accidental debug build.  Nearly every C++ performance question on this website has someone asking about that, so anyone who doesn't mention it has done zero prior research on SO, and is wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Amen to that. - "Why is this code slow?" - "Well, what optimizations did you enable?" - "Huh, what do you mean optimizations enabled?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found，as @manni66 pointed out, I made a big mistake..  I used Debug mode , when I changed to Release mode, the result was reasonable:

```
[1] vector<char*>(qsort) Elapsed time: 0.559000
[2] vector<char*>(sort) Elapsed time: 0.530000
Other test:
[3] char array(qsort)   Elapsed time: 0.512000
[3] vector<string>(sort) Elapsed time: 0.620000
```

Answer (score 14):

There are many problems in your benchmark that prevent you from making any conclusions form it:

1. You compare `std::sort`ing a `std::vector` of `std::strings` with `qsort`ing an array of `char*`s. Proper benchmark should use the same data structures.
2. An set size of 6 is not representative for benchmark by a few orders of magnitude.
3. Both algorithms sort in place, so despite performing one million iterations each, only first actually performs sort. The following 999999 iteration "sort" already sorted data.
4. You don't do anything meaningful with sorted data, so compiler might even remove your code.

Comment: @el.pescado Thank you very much, I just started learning C + +, what you said is very useful to me

Comment: Well, according to all the arrogant Stroupstrupian statements about C++ performance, all C++ containers should be just as fast as C arrays. Even though no human being has ever managed to produced machine code where this is true. Therefore it makes perfect sense to compare `std::sort` of a `std::vector<std::string>` with `qsort` of a raw 2D `char` array. You'll get a great measurement of how much BS various C++ fundamentalist dogmas contain.